# C# iterate over MapLocationFinderResult

Tags: c#, xaml, maps

I'm stumped on attempting to get more than one item from a MapLocationFinderResult list.
I've tried using a foreach loop:

```
private async void GetRouteAndDirections()
    {
        // Query hint
        queryHint = new BasicGeoposition();
        queryHint.Latitude = -37.8136;
        queryHint.Longitude = 144.9631;
        Geopoint hintPoint = new Geopoint(queryHint);

        // Start
        //BasicGeoposition startLocation = new BasicGeoposition();
        result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync(addressToGeocode, hintPoint, 10);

        // End

        // Get route

        // Show
        if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
        {
            foreach (MapLocation i in result.Locations)
            {
                txtMessage.Text += (result.Locations[i].Address.Street + " \n"); // need to figure out how to iterate over this
            }

            AddMapIcon();
        }
```

The error is:

*Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: **cannot convert from 'Windows.Services.Maps.MapLocation' to 'int'**    MapsApp C:\Users\Robert\OneDrive\VSProjects\MapsApp\MapsApp\MainPage.xaml.cs    72  Active*

Should I be trying to cast it, somehow?

This is using Windows.Services.Maps; Windows.Devices.Geolocation; Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is of type `MapLocation`,but you are trying to use it as an index. Try this code:

```
foreach (MapLocation i in result.Locations)
{
    txtMessage.Text += (i.Address.Street + " \n"); 
}
```